# Does SystemVerilog support global functions?

Tags: function, global, system-verilog

I want to make a parity_check function which can be accessed by three different modules. Is this possible in SV? If yes, where do I declare this function and how do I import it into my module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put a function into a separate file and include it using `include:

```
`include "some_file_name.sv"
```

However, a much better way is to use a *package*:

```
package some_package_name;
  function string some_function_name;
    return "some_function_name called";
  endfunction
endpackage
```

You would put that into a separate file and you must compile that before compiling any module that uses it. You then *import* the package into each module:

```
module some_module_name;
  import some_package_name::*;   // or import some_package_name::some_function_name;
  initial
    $display(some_function_name);
endmodule
```

Putting a function in a package is better than just putting it into a file and using *include*, because a package is a *named scope*. Because a package is a named scope, any issues with some clash of names can be resolved by, instead of using *import*, referring to the full name of the function in its package, eg:

```
module some_module_name;
  initial
    $display(some_package_name::some_function_name);
endmodule
```